# Prove that $a-b^{-1}$ and $(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a$ are units of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $a,b \in R$ such that $a$, $b$ and $ab-1$ are units.  Show that $a-b^{-1}$ and $(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a^{-1}$ are units and the following identity holds
$$[(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a^{-1}]^{-1}=aba-a$$

The first one is a unit because the unit elements of R form a group under multiplication and $a-b^{-1}=(ab-1)b^{-1}$, it follows that $a-b^{-1}$ is a unit.

For the second one, I can't express it as product of the unit elements so I tried showing directly that $aba-a$ is the inverse element of $(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a^{-1}$

$(aba-a)[(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a^{-1}]=(ab-1)[a(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-1]=(ab-1)[(1-a^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}-1]$

But it doesn't seem like going anywhere.  Is there a simple trick I'm missing here?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Side note: this is called Hua's identity.

Answer (score 1):

Observe
\begin{align}
(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-a^{-1} =&\ a^{-1}(a(a-b^{-1})^{-1}-1)\\
=&\ a^{-1}([(a-b^{-1})a^{-1}]^{-1}-1)\\
=&\  a^{-1}([(ab-1)b^{-1}a^{-1}]^{-1}-1)\\
=&\ a^{-1}(ab[ab-1]^{-1}-1)\\
=&\ a^{-1}(ab-[ab-1])[ab-1]^{-1} = -a^{-1}[1-ab]^{-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $(a-b^{-1})^{-1}$ can be rewritten as $(ba-1)^{-1}b$ (just multiply it by $(a-b^{-1})$ to see that this is true). Then, the claim follows easily from calculations similar to the ones you were already carrying on.